# Search Bar Magento Not Showing Correct Results

Tags: magento, search-engine, searchbar

On my website, www.parkplace.com when using the search bar I type in red mercades c class it shows me all red cars, all mercades and all c classes. I would like the search bar to be used to narrow it to only show me red mercades c classes. When using the search options on the side it works. Does anyone have any insite to this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try changing search type to fulltext instead of the default 'like' and reindex Catalog Search Index:
[image: admin search change]